# how to translate English to Japanese in Android Studio

Tags: android, localization, resources, android-resources

Hi guys and idea how to translate English to Japanese on Android Studio using localization? I found some tutorials but they translate it using strings.xml. Anyone knows how to translate it programmatically?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: It`s pretty obvious that I just want to create an application that can translate from english to japanese.

Comment: No, I mean why would you bypass the easy-to-use setup that exists now? Doing it programmatically would just be a waste of your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use translate api 'https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs' .

Do the following instructions

[image: Create new String values]

[image: Choose Language]

[image: Open translate editor]

[image: Order a translate]

Choose Language

Open translate editor
Order a translate

Comment: While doing so would be the obvious choice; they want to *not* do that in favor of implementing it themselves programmatically :(